# Background service triggered by external app gives no connection

Tags: android, background, connection, broadcast, networkinfo

I have two apps. One with a service that execute requests to a server. The other app that send broadcast events to the system to trigger the service that will send the request.

When the service is triggered, the app is in background and network info gives `state: DISCONNECTED/BLOCKED` and I can't send request to the server, even if the device is actually connected to Internet.

Is this normal?

Comment: You have a foreground service?

Comment: Are you testing on android O or higher? It had big changes regarding background services and broadcasts.

Comment: No, the service runs only when triggered from other apps and is in background

Comment: Pawel no no is Android 5!

Comment: @Cooper have you added internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes! I've tested by trigger the service from the app that contains it when is running and is all ok. Only if it triggered by other apps appears this problem